# WPF Cannot position tabitem headers to left

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, tabs

I have a tab control in my WPF application and I'm trying to position the TabItem headers to the left as shown in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00a521b2-5725-49f3-a4ca-8b9700d1afa4/is-it-possible-to-create-a-verticle-selection-menu-in-using-wpf-which-is-like-windows-azure-?forum=wpf) MSDN post using the below code (copied from the post):

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
    <TabItem Name="TabOne" Header="Tab One">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
                Tab One Here.
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Name="TabTwo" Header="Tab Two">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
               Tab Two here.
            </TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

According to the post this is what Im supposed to get:

[image]

But this is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

I've copied the exact same code from the post to my application and can't understand what has gone wrong.

Here is my full xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="OptionsWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TabStripPlacementSample" Height="200" Width="250" UseLayoutRounding="True">
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0,0,33,10">
        <TabItem Name="TabOne" Header="Tab One">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
                Tab One Here.
                </TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="TabTwo" Header="Tab Two">
            <TabItem.Content>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
               Tab Two here.
                </TextBlock>
            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full XAML? Currently I cannot find any issue with your code

Comment: Your screenshot look a bit different, which container element do you use? For example in your screenshot the TabControl does not use the full width...

Comment: @DannySchneider I have now edited the question and pasted the full xaml. Please go through it.

Comment: @DannySchneider Im using a grid to contain the TabControl

Comment: Mhh, when I copy your code one to one, I get your expected behavior. Have you tried to create a new clean application and paste the code their?

Comment: @DannySchneider Not yet but I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @DannySchneider The same code when pasted in a new application gives the results as desired.

Comment: @DannySchneider Im using AdonisUI for theming my older application, If that's anyway causing the problem?

Comment: I don't know AdonisUI, but as it seems to be a theming framework, it is definitely possible that styles from there will side effect your new window... So maybe you check the docu from AdonisUI and try to find out, how to style the TabControl to get needed design...

Comment: @DannySchneider ok